# Maven: how to deploy updated resources?

Tags: maven

I am having trouble getting a good work flow using Maven for a webapp.

My `context.xml` fragment points to the `target/MY_WEB_APP` folder and so I would like a quick way to get modified resource files into that folder.

My resource files are in `src/main/resources` and they get copied to `target/classes` when I run Maven `resources:resources`. However unless I run a full build I don't get those files in the `target/MY_WEB_APP` folder. The full build takes a couple of minutes and I only want to copy the modified resource files.

All of the resources are classpath resources and are hot swappable as the frameworks can be set to auto-reload. An example is the Struts config files that are auto-reloaded on each request as I have set `struts.devMode=true`. Hence if I can get it into the correct location then I don't need to do a full build.

Currently I have a text editor that has the open resource file `target/MY_WEB_APP/WEB-INF/classes/my-resource.xml` and I manually copy the modified file from my IDE into the editor. This is obviously a very, very silly way to work and there must be a better way.

How can this be done without the manual copy and paste?

Comment: What sort of resources are we talking about here? The method you've described relates to resources on the java classpath and they probably aren't hot-swappable because they could include things like spring configurations that could reconfigure your whole server, dropping classes, adding new ones, and the likes. If you're talking about html etc. then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Updated the question to add that all resources are classpath resources and all are hot swappable.

Comment: My point wasn't that your files aren't hot-swappable, it's that neither java nor intellij ca know that they're hot-swappable because they are on the classpath. I believe your use-case is supported somewhat in java 8, spring, and jRebel, but support is far from perfect and you're likely to have problems. IntelliJ has the ability to deploy resources to your webapp when you run it from the ide, but only if it's already running, and only for static resources (jsp, html, etc.). What you're asking for is far from normal.

Comment: I was keeping the question as simple as possible. All the resources concerned are hot-swappable. Struts devMode and JRebel handle those issues but they are irrelevant to the problem.

As I implied in the question, a manual copy and paste works perfectly well and I am simply looking for a way to copy ONLY the resource through Maven to the apps build folder.

Comment: Write a shell script, invoke it from idea's tool menu or add a keybinding to it. Like I said, this isn't at all normal, and it isn't supported directly by your toolset because of the problems I outlined above.

Comment: Thanks, you raise an interesting point. At the risk of going of topic surely modifying a resource file will either cause hot-swap if the framework allows it or it will be ignored if it does not.

Comment: There's no real difference between a resource and a java-ish class. Both are on the classpath and have the capability to change everything in your application. Our tools don't know prima facie what changes on the classpath will do; they just know that it can be catastrophic so they tend to treat it all as if it will be. Also, even in wars, the deployment structure is variable and depends on your maven/gradle config -- your tool can guess how you've configured it, but it'd be guessing in most cases -- how can it know where to unpack the resources without running the build to pack them up first?